# Tensor flow DNN intermitent error

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am using a Tensor Flow DNN classifier to recognize emotions in images. The training accuracy I am getting is around 80%. However, if I run the application again (fully train and test) I occasionally get a really low test accuracy, around 25%. This is without changing any code or dataset.

I understand that the initial weights are randomized in DNN classifiers but that would not give such a large difference in test accuracy.

I am using 23 features and have tested with varying sizes of datasets (50 - 1000 images). The intermittent low test accuracy always exists.

Comment: You're going to have to show some code or this is a question that's too abstract, we can't reproduce your results or see what you've attempted.

Comment: Update. I managed to solve the problem by saving the classifier once trained and then reloading it for testing. Annoyingly I didn't identify the problem but that seems to have solved it.